How can I convert complex numbers with conjugates and modulus into the standard form of z=x+iy?
How can I convert $\ z=\frac{\overline{2+3i}}{\lvert{2+3i}\rvert} $ into the form of $\ z=x+yi$ where the numerator of fraction represents the conjugate and the denominator represents the modulus. I initially began by changing up the conjugate into its form of $\ 2-3i$ and the modulus into its form $\ \sqrt{2+3i} $  but I am struggling to understand how to continue from there on.

If I don't change its form and instead just compute by multiplying both numerator and denominator by the conjugate of 2-3i then I change the form at the end of the calculations I get $\ \frac{-5}{5i} $

$|2+3i|=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}\neq\sqrt{2+3i}$

This helped a lot. I missed this in my teacher's notes. Thank you.

Directly computing:
$$\frac{2 - 3i}{\sqrt{13}} = \frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13} - \frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}i$$

Alternate method (for fun):
Recall that $\bar{z}/|z|^2 = z^{-1}$, so that what you have here is:
$$\frac{z}{|2+3i|} = \frac{\overline{2+3i}}{|2+3i|^2} = \frac{1}{2+3i}$$
From the first and third expression, this yields
$$z = \frac{|2+3i|}{2+3i} = \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2+3i}$$
At this point, you can rationalize the denominator to find your final answer:
$$\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2+3i} \cdot \frac{2-3i}{2-3i} = \frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13} - \frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}i$$
Luckily, both paths lead to the same answer!

I just solved it through your first method. Thank you so much! I appreciate the alternate method as well.
